# command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11 Firebase Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am storing the user data in `userUID` a subchild of  `users` node of firebase. But facing the error command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11, I have researched a number of relevant questions, but did not find similar to this. Help me to accomplish this.

```
  let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

  var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


  ref.child("users").child(userID!).setValue{(self.emailTextField.text!, self.passwordTextField.text!, self.fullName.text!, self.numberText.text!, self.countryText.text!)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).setValue{(self.emailTextField.text!, self.passwordTextField.text!, self.fullName.text!, self.numberText.text!, self.countryText.text!)
```

I count six forced unwrappings of optional types. Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect which one of

- userId
- self.emailTextField.text
- self.passwordTextField.text
- self.fullName.text
- self.numberText.text
- self.countryText.text

is nil.

Comment: even i put breakpoint but still same error and i also have removed `!` from fields given

Comment: OK. Add the stack trace to your question